# Find people recently added to Google+ circles

Tags: google-plus-circles

I think I just added a bunch of people to my Google+ circles, sort of by accident. How do quickly find the recently added people?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to G+ profile.
2. Select people from left panel.
3. Go to your circles.
4. Select Recently updated from the drop down list.

Comment: Whatever "Recently updated" means, it's not what I would like. I cannot make sense of the order.

Comment: true, As of now, ASAIK this is what they are providing.